# How to Order By in PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

Guys I Have A Little Problem
I Want sort data by id in pivot.. 
you can try this through [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/493ef/13)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the use of `Person_Id` in the `COUNT()` statement.  The following works:

```
SELECT Person_Id, Name, 
       [Honda], [Suzuki], [Yamaha], [Harley Davidson]
FROM (SELECT P.Name, PM.MotorCycle, PM.Person_id
      FROM Person P LEFT JOIN
           dbo.Person_MotorCycle PM
           ON P.Person_Id = PM.Person_Id    
     ) AS ST 
PIVOT (COUNT(MotorCycle)
       FOR MotorCycle IN
       ([Honda], [Suzuki], [Yamaha], [Harley Davidson]
       )
   ) PIV
ORDER BY Person_Id;
```

Comment: heem,, yop it's work but it's not way i want..
ID  Name
1   Jusuf
2   Rajeev
3   Teguh
4   Darmawan
5   Ari

I want appear accordance with the id,,

Comment: nop,,, i just want sort by id,,, not appear the ID,, im just give the id for your information....

Comment: @user3606622 . . . I have no idea what your issue is.  You can sort by `person_id`, with or without selecting it.  There is no other id in your data.